# SWRevealViewController hiding rear view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

I am designing a slide out menu using SWRevealViewController. I have a TableViewController with static cells to be my rear view controller. The table view goes like -

[image]

I want my slide out menu to be like this only but instead I get something like this as SWRevealViewController cuts some part of my rear view conroller -

[image]

I want that my slide menu must have a full display of my rearViewController still showing the open button. Please give suggestions or code if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a full width rearViewController, you can do this:

> 1. Go to `-(void)_initDefaultProperties` in SWRevealViewController.m class.
> 2. Change `_rearViewRevealWidth = 260.0f;` to `_rearViewRevealWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;`

You can also modify other dimensions in same method.

Comment: But it would hide my front view controller completely & my open button would not be shown? I want the width being same can't we load an entire view controller in it?

Comment: @NataMio I am asking that I want that my slide menu must have a full display of my rearViewController still showing the open button.

Comment: Side bar is usually used for displaying ViewController only partially, you have to design your ViewController such as it shows all the options in that partial view.

Comment: So there is no way to do as I want.

Comment: You can do this to adjust your side view, `_rearViewRevealWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width*0.9;` . Change the **0.9** value so as to adjust your screen.

Comment: @G.Abhisek There is a way actually, if you can give same Menu Button on side bar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99924/discussion-between-g-abhisek-and-arpit).

Comment: @Arpit Dongre  but how to make SWReveal change its way from pushing the view that called him to cover the cover it like Gmail App

Answer (score 1):

That's why because it has 260 as width static value and to change that you need to open `SWrevealviewcontroller.m` file , scroll to line 647 and change the width of the `_rearViewControllerWidth` from 260 to 360 for example !

Good luck !

Answer (score -1):

There is one property named `rightViewRevealWidth` in SWRevealViewController. You can change its value.

in your first viewController add below line in `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 80.0;
```

Comment: Sorry, after implementing this code, my screen goes black after launch screen